# llvm: strategies to build JIT content incrementally

Tags: llvm, llvm-3.0, incremental-compiler

I want my language backend to build functions and types incrementally but don't pollute the main module and context when functions and types fail to build successfully (due to problems with the user input).

I ask [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9104282/170521) regarding this.
One strategy i can see for this would be building everything in temp module and `LLVMContext`, migrating to main context only after success, but i am not sure if that is possible with the current API. For instance, i wouldn't know know to migrate that content between different contexts, as they are supposed to represent isolated islands of LLVM functionality, but maybe there is always the alternative to save everything to .bc and load somewhere else?

what other strategies would you suggest for achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have two modules - source and destination, it's possible to copy a function from source to destination. The code in LLVM you can use as an example is the body of the LLVM linker, in `lib/linker/LinkModules.cpp`.

In particular, look at the `linkFunctionProto` and `linkFunctionBody` methods in that file. `linkFunctionBody` copies the function definition, and uses the `llvm::CloneFunctionInto` utility for the heavy lifting.

---

As for `LLVMContext`, unless you specifically need to run several LLVM instances simultaneously in different threads, don't worry about it too much and just use `getGlobalContext()` everywhere a context is required. Read [this doc page](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#llvmcontext) for more information.

Comment: i specifically need to keep multiple LLVMContexts because they are called from a long-running service process, and keeping a global LLVMContext would probably make it grow unbounded. Individual LLVMContexts will make for better memory management and garbage collection (even when run inside a single-threaded process)

Comment: @lurscher: I seriously doubt that it "would probably make it grow unbounded". I would suggest you to implement it using a single context and benchmark / do profiling. Most likely memory usage will be insignificant. As the page I linked to says, you just can't pass in-memory data structures between contexts. I imagine you could serialize them to bitcode and de-serialized them on the other side (in a different context) though

Comment: in any case, i want to refer you this post on the mailing list regarding long running process and memory management

Comment: it seems i forgot to paste the url: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2012-February/047371.html